# Vuetify: v-datepicker doesn't display all days for each months

Tags: vue.js, date, datepicker, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I am trying to use the date picker from Vuetify. However no matter where I am placing my component v-datepicker in the code, only the four first weeks are displayed. For example, I cannot see after June 26th, July 24th, etc. I am missing the last few days for every months. Does someone had a similar issue please? You can find here a screen shot of the issue: [screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiKat.png)
Thank you

```html
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-date-picker v-model="picker"></v-date-picker>
  </v-row>
```